# PHP DateTime conversion error

Tags: php, datetime, date-math

I am using this code:

```
//get days
$a = date_create($arrive);
$d = date_create($leave);
//$days = date_diff($d,$a);

echo '<input type="hidden" id="days" value="'.date_diff($d,$a).'"/>';
```

and getting this error: Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateInterval could not be converted to string

I do not know how to fix the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`date_diff()` returns a `DateInterval` object which you need to call `format()` on to get the actual value from it. In this case you will use `%d` to get the number of days.

```
//get days
$a = date_create($arrive);
$d = date_create($leave);
$diff = date_diff($d,$a);

echo '<input type="hidden" id="days" value="'.$diff->format("%d").'"/>';
```

Just keep in mind this will only go up to 31. From there you will need to use `%m` with `%d` to also display months.

[**See it in action**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ZsOuws)

Comment: You can just use `$diff->days` (or `$diff->d`) :-D

Comment: @RocketHazmat I *always* forget about that!

Comment: The error went away but when I do a log of the hidden input it says undefined.

Comment: Can you provide us with valid values for `$arrive` and `$leave` so we cna do better testing?

Comment: `$arrive = '2013-10-01'; $leave = '2013-10-11';` That what you mean?

I even made the input a textbox to make sure the number got there and it did. I am using this to acces it: `var days = $('#days').val();`

Comment: Ok, the code I provided [does work](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ZsOuws) so the problem isn't there. This means it lies elsewhere and probably should be a new question if you can't figure it out.

Comment: @RocketHazmat & @JohnConde: `$diff->days` and `$diff->d` are not the same things. `->days` returns the TOTAL number of days between datetimes, where `->d` only returns number of days with carry over points, so `->d` cannot be larger than 31...